# Не работает выборка из обернутого элемента

Tags: jquery

Не работает выборка из обернутого элемента?

```
console.log($(".welcome_input")[1].val())

console.log($(".welcome_input").get(0).val())

var a = $(".welcome_input")
console.log(a[1].val())
```

Везде ошибка

```
  TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всё правильно:

`$(".welcome_input")[1]` возвращает не jQuery object, а DOM-елемент, у которого соответсвенно нету метода `val()`

можете воспользоваться селектором [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)  или методом [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$(".welcome_input:first").val();
$(".welcome_input").first().val()
```

если нужно обратиться по произвольному индексу воспользуйтесь селектором [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) или методом [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

а вообще, используйте id